# after() is not updating my Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a mini game that generates a random word from the letters A-G and asks the user to spell that word on a MIDI controller. Before, I had the code working fine in the command line using a while loop, but once I started creating a GUI, obviously the while loop will not work.

I've done research and was advised to use the after() method to 'refresh' that function so it updates the GUI window. However, it is not doing so. I would like the window to print which note was pressed each time, printing it out in a list. I've spent all day trying to figure it out, to no avail.

My code so far:

```
def spelling_func(self):
    """ Lesson 1: Spelling Game
        MINI GAME that generates a random word & asks user to spell it out using piano keyboard."""

    piano = PianoInput() # Class that reads in MIDI input
    spelling = SpellingGame()
    text = Tkinter.Text(self.window.after(1), bg="black", fg="red", font="Helvetica")

    # Generates random word from dict.
    spelling.random_word_gen()

    # Asks user to spell random word
    text.insert('insert', "Please spell the word: " + spelling.word)
    text.pack()

    #while spelling.isTrue:
    piano.detect_key()
    if piano.piano_key == [] or piano.piano_key[0][0][0] == 128:
        pass
    else:
        #Prints the note pressed.
        text.insert('insert', piano.display_note(piano.piano_key[0][0][1]))
        text.pack()

        print piano.display_note(piano.piano_key[0][0][1])

        spelling.user_input = spelling.input_to_list(piano.piano_key[0][0][1])

        user_input_notes = []

        # Cycles through user input list & converts returned number to what key is pressed. Then adds to list.
        for item in spelling.user_input:
            temp_key = piano.display_note(item)

            parsed_note = piano.parse_key(temp_key)

            user_input_notes.append(parsed_note)
            print "user input notes"
            print user_input_notes
            print "Generated word"
            print spelling.generated_word

            spelling.win_or_lose(user_input_notes)

            # continue
        self.after(0, self.spelling_func)
```

I've commented out where the original while loop was just to give an idea. If needed, this method calls another method from a different class, the definition for that is below:

```
 def win_or_lose(self, user_input_notes):
    i = 0  # Counter for list positions.

    # If notes are correct.
    if user_input_notes == self.generated_word:
        print 'CONGRATS!'
        winsound.PlaySound('sound/sfx/OOT_Song_Correct.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        # Clears out all previous input & generated words
        self.generated_word = []
        self.user_input = []
        user_input_notes = []

        self.random_word_gen()

        # Asks user to spell random word
        print "Please spell the word: " + self.word

    # If user gets note wrong.
    elif user_input_notes[i] != self.generated_word[i]:
        print 'WRONG!'
        winsound.PlaySound('sound/sfx/OOT_Song_Error.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        # Clears out all previous input
        self.user_input = []
        user_input_notes = []
        i = 0

        print "Try again!"
        print "\n"
        print "Please spell the word: " + self.word

    else:
        i += 1
```

Thanks in advance. I apologize for it being sloppy, I'm not too familiar with programming with GUIs.

Comment: Don't use a while loop in tkinter, ever- the tkinter mainloop **is** a while loop that updates the interface and everything. Putting your own in there will not allow the gui to do anything. You need to use `.after()` with a function that also schedules itself.

Comment: you shouldn't use `after(0, ...)`. The event loop never gets a chance to process other events because the "after" queue never empties. You should always give a non-zero time. This may not be the only problem, but it's likely part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution. It turns out i was using after(0,...) which made it skip over the after(), as Bryan had said. I changed it to after(1,...). I then split up that function into two different functions since the beginning part did not need to loop, only the part where the #while isTrue is commented out.

I then placed the after() at the end of the second function and with a bit more tweaking, it worked! Thank you :)